# Add Calendar list to WikiPage using Powershell

Tags: web-part, powershell

I have inserted a Calendar list to a page(SitePages/Home.aspx) using a powershell script, But I want to insert it in to a specific location as shown in image. When I insert the calendar list it insert it to the Bottom of the page by default even If I specify zone as right. The SitePages/Home.aspx has only "Bottom" zone(verified using SPD) and I assume that's the reason its inserting in to Bottom Zone by default. Even if I try to edit the Page it doesn't display the Bottom Zone with calendar.

How do I Specify the Zone location and Index?

```
$wpManager.AddWebPart($wpView,"Right",0)
```

[image]

Any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I have blogged about it here. http://kannabirank.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/sharepoint-power-shell-script-to-add-webpart-to-wiki-page/